# не правильный Request запрос

Tags: python, requests, beautiful-soup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from time import sleep
from fake_useragent import UserAgent


response = requests.get('https://belgorod.hh.ru/search/resume?text=Программист&area=17&clusters=true&exp_period=all_time&logic=normal&pos=full_text', headers={'User-Agent': UserAgent().chrome})

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)

namejob = soup.find_all("div", class_="resume-search-item__header")

print(namejob)
```

Запрос должен вывести первого человека. У него параметры "Программист" "31 год"

А запрос выводит:

```
 <div class="resume-search-item__header" data-qa="resume-serp__resume-header"><a class="resume-search-item__name HH-VisitedResume-Href HH-LinkModifier" data-qa="resume-serp__resume-title" href="/resume/7052eea40002be1c8d0039ed1f48666b326952?query=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82&amp;source=search"
    itemprop="jobTitle" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">Специалист</a><span class="output__right"></span>
  <div class="resume-search-item__fullname" data-qa="resume-serp__resume-fullname" itemprop="name"><span data-qa="resume-serp__resume-age">28 лет</span></div>
  <div class="resume-search-item__compensation"></div>
</div>
```

Как видим. "Специалист" "28 лет"

Comment: Походу он парсит не белгородский hh.ru. Где косяк, подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Просто зайдите на страницу, которую вы парсите и увидите, что видим `"Специалист" "28 лет"` . С чего вы взяли, что должно быть что-то другое ?

Comment: Уже решили проблему с Twiss. Дело в том, что я залогинен под "компанией" и там другой список

Comment: @S.Nick Не могли бы помочь? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/941179/Как-залогиниться-на-hh-ru-с-помощью-requests