# Как залогиниться на hh.ru с помощью requests

Tags: python, request

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from time import sleep
from fake_useragent import UserAgent    

sess = requests.Session()
sess.verify = False

response = sess.post('https://belgorod.hh.ru/login', data={'username': 'xxxx', 'password': 'xxxxx'}, headers={'User-Agent': UserAgent().chrome})

response = sess.get('https://belgorod.hh.ru/search/resume?text=Программист&area=17&clusters=true&exp_period=all_time&logic=normal&pos=full_text', headers={'User-Agent': UserAgent().chrome})

print(response)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)

namejob = soup.find("div", class_="resume-search-item__header")

print(namejob)
```

Не логинится на hh.ru

Comment: вы уверены что корректно сформировали post запрос?

Comment: @garrythehotdog не знаю, в этом то и дело. Прошу помочь

Comment: включите режим разработчика в браузере и посмотри какие http запросы отправляются на сервер hh, потом просто повторите их

Comment: @garrythehotdog Включил, но не смог поймать нужный post запрос на сайте https://belgorod.hh.ru/login

Comment: @МаксимХалин почему бы не использовать HH API ?

Comment: @VadimPopov Уже сделал и проект закончил давно. Так не интересно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В первую очередь советую, Вам почитать про `инструменты разработчика` в браузере и как их использовать. И о том как работают формы на сайтах. Вот не большой **не рабочий** пример, который нужно дополнить. Я думаю после того как Вы почитаете, Вы поймете что нужно дополнить.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def xsrf(text):
    bs = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html5lib')
    xsrf = bs.find('input', {'name': "_xsrf", 'type': "hidden"})

    return xsrf


def authorize(login, passw):
    text = requests.get('https://belgorod.hh.ru/account/login').text
    post = requests.post(
        'https://belgorod.hh.ru/account/login?backurl=/',
        data={
            'backUrl': 'https://belgorod.hh.ru/',
            'failUrl': r'/account/login?backurl=%2F',
            'username': login,
            'password': passw,
            'remember': 'yes',
            '_xsrf': xsrf(text)
        },
        allow_redirects=False
    )


authorize('maxim_halin', 'SO test')
```

Comment: `xsrf = bs.find('input', {'name': "_xsrf", 'type': "hidden"})['value']`
Вот и вся доработка. Спасибо большое. Выручили. Благодаря вам научился искать post запросы XD